# Summary of all IBOutlet, IBAction connections in a project?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

Is there a tool or trick for displaying all the connections between objects in an Xcode project?  I'm thinking of some kind of graphical display, or less desirably, a table.  Naturally this would be very useful for troubleshooting or studying sample code.  I tried searching in here (SO) but the terms appear in many questions and connections has another meaning.  Thanks.

Comment: By 'objects', do you mean instances? Or classes? Good question though. Such a tool would be helpful.

Comment: I mean objects like buttons and labels.  As a newbie, I keep breaking my code as I add stuff to a working project; usually I find that the connections are not right.  I'm looking for a tool to keep track of them so I can compare working to not-working, or just understand better!

Comment: I don't believe there is any tool that meets your goal today. The basis of such a tool would be `ibtool`. Check the man page for it to see how it works and the kind of output it generates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Rob Napier's suggestion, something like "ibtool --connections foo.xib" might help.  See http://cocoapi.wordpress.com/2009/02/20/how-to-look-for-a-specific-bind/ for some grunt stuff that might help as well.

I am new to this, too, and coming from android side.  I wonder if it's better in the long run to define all connections dynamically in the view controller as needed, if that can be done in all scenarios.  At least you can see how everything is hooked up there in one place.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  I went ahead and redirected the output to a text file for detailed study, but I see what it does.  Surprising to me that Apple doesn't make available a graphical version, it's clearly ripe for conversion.  I'm going to mark yours as the accepted answer and upvote Rob.

Answer (score 0):

In IB, you can simply click on File's Owner instead of on individual elements and it will show all available IBOutlets and IBActions in the right sidebar and what they are connected to.

Comment: For me, clicking on File's Owner while the nib is displayed shows only  a limited number of connections.  What I'm thinking of is a summary of all the connections you would get if you clicked on each element individually.  So I guess I'm looking for connections between buttons, labels, and the class/instance methods that make them work.  I hope this is a little clearer.

Comment: So you mean like the "touch up inside" method of uibuttons, etc? That isn't currently possible.